# Connect to Database using WCF Service

Tags: .net, wcf, web-services, sql-server-2008-r2

I want to connect the database (sql server 2008 R2) to my sample WCF service created.

It is very clear that i did not created any client till now and do not want to create client too and i am testing my WCF service using WCF Test Client only...

Now my point is,

1. How to connect step by step the database to WCF service...
2. In How many ways can we connect database to WCF Services..

Provide me any usefull links and thanks in advance....

Answer (score 0):

Use [SQLCLR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254498.aspx):

- [Enable SQLCLR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131048.aspx)
- [Load `System.ServiceModel` into the database](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345106.aspx)
- [Create a function/stored proc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131094.aspx)
- Call the web service. There are tons of details and examples among the [Internets](https://www.google.com/search?q=sql+clr+wcf).